# Create Database in Visual Studio as a new database project and then use it as a test database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, visual-studio, oracle

I wish to create a database in Visual Studio as a new database project and then use it as a test database to select/insert/delete/update/etc. Currently I have my program connected to the production database and I only do my testing during downtime or turnarounds.  Is there a way I can manually create a similar database or copy a piece of the existing database and use that as the database that my code runs off of.  I am using Visual Studio 2010 and c#.NET
Thanks,

DE

Answer (score 0):

Create a backup of the production database, copy it to your system. Then create a new database on your system. Restore the backup you made to your new database

check here: 
http://kb.eukhost.com/backup-and-restore-ms-sql-server-2008-database/
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-sql-server-database-backups

If you have access to Management Studio, it would be easier

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response.  I am working with an old Oracle Database and my privileges are limited.  I found a video on youtube that outlined exactly what I wanted to do:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3w2JkLcp-UA
I would like to write my entire program using the tables I created and then change a few things at the end to have it communicate with the actually Oracle production database.

Comment: Ok. Add the "Oracle" tag to your question